# Safety of exposing document IDs for "anyone with the link can view"-style functionality

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an API endpoint that I'm using to return some data from a Cloud Firestore collection.

The data it returns is largely insensitive, but it's publicly callable, so I'm not using auth for this endpoint. I wouldn't want the collections to be listable, i.e. **I want it to act like "anyone with the link can view" data.**

I'm looking up data for a subcollection's document, so currently the call would look like something like this:

`GET endpoint.example/?parentDoc=XXXX0000XXXX&subDoc=XXXX0000XXXXX`

I was considering creating a separate "references" collection with a UUID or something to represent the two, in case revealing the document IDs like that is considered a bad practice(?) — e.g.

`GET endpoint.example/?myOwnRef=123-234-123-234-ABC-DEF`

Assuming I have the Firestore locked down with appropriate security rules, is it safe to assume that the *only* benefit I'd get from further hashing / creating my own (e.g. UUID) reference for the parent doc / subcollection doc is [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)?

...Or is there more merit to further obscuring the IDs here if I'm after a private / shareable link style functionality to reference the data?

EDIT: As *Doug Stevenson* pointed out, this question refers to autogenerated Firestore document IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if your document IDs actually contain any data in them.  If they are just randomly generated, then good security rules should be sufficient to prevent someone from doing something they're not supposed to with a document if they know the ID.  There is no advantage to hashing it, since it's already an opaque value.

If the ID does contain some data, then you are putting that data into the hands of someone who might do something with it that you'd not like, and you might want to remove that from view by hashing it.

Comment: Good catch there! I meant the auto-generated ones, yes :) Just hadn't had this use-case yet and wanted to be sure. Appreciate the fast answer there! Will update post to clarify...